# What would happen if I uncheck "Exclusive rights to owner" in Folder Redirection GPO Editor?

Tags: group-policy, folder-redirection

I was "debugging" my Folder Redirection GPO

What would happen if I uncheck "Exclusive rights to owner" in Folder Redirection GPO Editor?

I'm interested in consequences. What would happen to the current user permissions?

Would it be applied to their folders as well? Or it works for new users only?

If you are interested, I am debugging this: https://serverfault.com/questions/327312/folder-redirection-gpo-is-not-working-for-certain-users-gpupdate-doesnt-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkbox (when checked) blocks permissions inheritance from the parent folder and grants only the user and System access to the redirected folders.

If you uncheck the box, nothing would happen to existing folders but new folders would inherit any permissions that would normally apply to the folders.